# Can I debug flutter android plugins from within VSCode?

Tags: android, flutter, debugging, visual-studio-code, plugins

I expect the answer is 'no' from what I've already found, but thought I'd ask the specific question.

I have a Flutter app which via a channel calls into an android plugin the java source for which is in the app source tree. Since one can also do java development in VS Code, I thought there might be a way to step into the plugin code while debugging the Flutter app, but so far no luck - the app doesn't "see" that the source for the plugin it's using is open in a VSC editor. Is there a way to configure for this? I've already installed the Java coding support extensions for VSC.

I like VSC because it's so lightweight, but if I have to use Android Studio to be able to code & debug both flutter and java plugin code in the same app that's fine. In which case how to configure for that?

Thanks!